# regex for text box to validate input

Tags: regex

i tried multiple examples to validate a string in textbox but could not get right answer.

1. first digit could be +,-,decimal point,any number. but all symbols should not repeat
   e.g ++ is invalid but 00 is valid
   2.after decimal it should allow only upto two digits but if user does not enters it should accept it.
   after decimal if user just enters 1 numeric digit that should be also fine
   e.g 1.1 and 1.23 and .3, and .43 all are valid but 11. and 11.. are not valid

some examples for valid and invalid
valid
1,1.0,.4,.45,+1,-2,-.3,-1.2,+.23,-.6,2.45 all are valid
invalid
++,1.234,.,1.+,2.300,...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
^[+-]?\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/2)